# The view showname.views.delete didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead

Tags: django

I have the next code in delete generic class:

```
class delete(DeleteView):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        def get_absolute_url(self):
            return  reverse('index')
```

There is the url patttern:

```
 url(r'^$', views.indext.as_view(), name='index'),
```

As i understand from the decumentation, if i want to redirect thr user to the index when he tryies to approach the page through the url by himself, i Call "get" which defind what to do when "get" messege sent, and then "get_absolute_url" with "reverse" to do the same method that "url" in html pages does. But it doesnt work. why it returning None as the page sayes?

Comment: i know dniel... from the tutorial i learning in youtube he dont explain this spesiphic setails, and my native is Hebrew so i dont really understand what are the deumentation of django want from me... please, if you can hellp me - or better, give me your skype or somthing so we can tallk more comfortable..

Comment: Well this isn't really about documentation or even about Django specifically; defining a function that only contains another function definition doesn't do anything at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Defining a `get_absolute_url` within the `get` function makes absolutely no sense. You *aren't* return anything from the `get` function itself, just as the error says.

There is no need for that nested function. If you want to redirect to the index page from your view, then just do that:

```
def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    return redirect('index')
```

Comment: thanks! it works now..ans reverse is just when i want to return some value to the url im going? (please also read the comment about my first messege..)

Comment: `reverse` is for getting the value of a URL. `redirect` is for actually going there. And please don't forget to accept my answer if it solved your problem.

Comment: just did... if you will be able to enter in here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39224562/i-got-confused-between-the-all-url-functions-in-django?noredirect=1#comment65786965_39224562 i really didnt understand (as you probobly already see :D) the all url thing. and i didnt got understand the decumantation.. it will be very appriciate, thanks!